# Is it required to have a google developer account to use firebase auth?

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-developers-console

I'm working on my first project
which is a student portal app on Android studio with firebase. I read all the documentation and followed the steps but whenever I add an account via my android application it doesn't appear on the users tab in the firebase console. Is it because I don't have a google developer account? I am hesitant to purchase an account because maybe it can be solved without going into the purchasing process. Please help me out

Comment: firebase is free to use so you don't need to pay for a developer account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need a developer account for publishing apps on playstore , otherwise all firebase services are free until you exceed some usage limits and can sign in using any gmail without paying any expenses. you can check the pricing plan of firebase and what you can access for free by following this link Visit  https://firebase.google.com/pricing